# In JavaFX, how do I tell which Stage is in front of another?

Tags: javafx

I have a JavaFX application with several Stages open to provide floating windows.  I want to iterate through these Stages from front to back.  I have a list of all the Stages which I'd like to sort and am looking for a method that will let me compare two of them and determine which is in front.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Sedrick good advice, as always :) Curious, though as I couldn't find any api to get hold of the z-order of windows, any idea?

Comment: I have no idea either,  but I was thinking since there is a list of stage that maybe the list could be use to keep up with the z-order.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you keep a list of Stages, can you not rearrange them whenever a stages receives focus? That way, the top stage could always be the first element in this list.

Answer (score 2):

This is just one possibility.

1. Store each open `Stage` in a list that can be observed for changes.
2. Add a listener on each Stage's `focusedProperty`. When it changes to true,
3. Remove the stage from our List and readd it at index 0
4. Now, create a listener on the List and your "focused" `Stage` will always be at index 0.

You now have an `ArrayList` that stores the open stages, in order.

Here is a simple MCVE to demonstrate.  There are certainly areas to be improved upon and I welcome suggestions, but this does provide some basic functionality.

**OpenStages.java:**

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;

/**
 * Implementation of a SimpleListProperty that will store our ObservableArrayList
 */
public class OpenStages<Stage> extends SimpleListProperty<Stage> {

    /**
     * Constructor that creates an ObservableArrayList
     */
    public OpenStages() {
        super(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
    }

    /**
     * Removes this Stage from the list and re-adds it at index 0
     */
    public void focusStage(Stage stage) {
        this.remove(stage);
        this.add(0, stage);
    }
}
```

**Main.java:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Custom SimpleListProperty that holds our ObservableArrayList of open stages
        OpenStages<Stage> openStages = new OpenStages<>();

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Button btnCreateStage = new Button("Create New Stage");
        btnCreateStage.setOnAction(event -> {

            // Create a new Stage
            Stage newStage = new Stage();

            // Add a listener to the focusedProperty of the Stage. When focus changes to true, we
            // need to update our openStages list
            newStage.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (newValue) {
                    openStages.focusStage(newStage);
                }
            });

            // Add the stage to our OpenStages list.
            openStages.add(newStage);

            // Simple layout for the new Stage
            VBox stageRoot = new VBox();
            stageRoot.setPrefSize(300, 100);
            stageRoot.setPadding(new Insets(10));
            stageRoot.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            // Let's add a label and title to indicate which Stage this is
            stageRoot.getChildren().add(new Label("Stage #" + openStages.size()));
            newStage.setTitle("Stage #" + openStages.size());

            newStage.setScene(new Scene(stageRoot));

            // Finally, let's show the stage
            newStage.show();

        });

        // Now, let's create a simple listener for our openStages list to print out the focused Stage
        openStages.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Stage>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends Stage> c) {
                // Only interested in a stage being added
                if (c.next() && c.wasAdded()) {
                    System.out.println("Focused stage: " + openStages.get(0).getTitle());
                }
            }
        });

        // Add the Button to our main layout
        root.getChildren().add(btnCreateStage);

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: good idea +1 :) Only: dont extend so much - the only reason for extension is added functionality - simple config by public api is clear contraindication

Comment: True, this could be done with a simple method to interact with the ObservableList directly.